# Unexpected result of remainder operator % in a while loop - Swift

Tags: swift4.1

I'm trying to find factors of a set of doubles, so I'm converting them to Integers first and finding the divisor using %.

### Option 1

The problem I have is that when the conversion happens in my loop, I'm loosing some information, particularly, if call the following function:

```
func factors(number: Double) -> [Double] {
    var result = [Double]()
    var divisor = 0.1

    let temporaryIncreasedNumber = Int(number) * 10

        while number > divisor {
            let theNewDivisor = divisor * 10
            print("\(divisor) * \(10) = \(theNewDivisor) for \(divisor), \(temporaryIncreasedNumber) % \(Int(theNewDivisor)) is \(temporaryIncreasedNumber % Int(theNewDivisor))")
            if temporaryIncreasedNumber % Int(theNewDivisor)  == 0 {
                //print ("dividing \(temporaryIncreasedNumber) by \(theNewDivisor) for \(divisor)")
                result.append(divisor);
            }

            divisor += 0.1
        }
    return result
}
```

for 20, so:

```
factors(number: 20.0))
```

If I look for example at the output:

```
1.1 * 10 = 11.0 for 1.1, 200 % 10 is 0
```

Somehow when I do the operation `200 % Int(1.1 * 10)`, the `Int(1.1 * 10)` is giving me a 10, rather than an 11, I don't know why? This of course passes the validation of `A % B == 0` but it shouldn't because `200 % 11 = 2`

I manually did the following in a Playground, but this worked fine and gave me the result of `200 % 11 = 2`

```
let myX = 20.0
let myY = 1.1
let myCalc = Int(myX * 10.0) % Int(myY * 10.0)
let myCalc2 = 200 % 11
```

### Option 2

Alternatively if I simply things and operate only with doubles, I still get inconsistent values. If I simplify the code to:

```
func factors(number: Double) -> [Double] {
    var result = [Double]()
    var divisor = 0.1

        while number > divisor {
            let whole = (number/divisor).rounded(.towardZero)
            print ("reminder of \(number) by \(divisor) = \((number/divisor) - whole)")
            if (number/divisor) - whole  == 0.0 {
                result.append(divisor);
            }

            divisor = divisor + 0.1
        }
    return result
}

factors(number: 20.0)
```

Do note that I'm not explicitly using truncating reminder so that I can check what's wrong.

Taking a look at the following operation, it gives an unexpected result:

```
reminder of 20.0 by 0.8 = 3.5527136788005e-15
```

But if I do the following manually in a playground:

```
let test = (20.0/0.8) - (20.0/0.8).rounded(.towardZero)
```

The result is 0!

---

Why is the behaviour different in the while loop? is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Apple directly, they advised that the issue is because of casting Int -> Double and visa versa. In their reply...

> Floating-point is binary-based, so 1.1 is not exactly the ideal value
>   1 1/10, it’s 1.09999….. , and 1.1 *10.0 is really 10.999…...
>   Double-to-Int conversion truncates

They advised to use Decimal instead if you require further precision which was my case. I've found a solution this way by using a combination of `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` operations (so that I can extract the double out of the decimal to round it).

```
func factors2(number: Double) -> [Decimal] {
    var result = [Decimal]()
    var divisor = Decimal(0.1)

    let decimalNumber = Decimal(number)

        while decimalNumber >= divisor {

            let operation = (decimalNumber/divisor)
            let wholeDecimal = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: operation)
            let whole = wholeDecimal.doubleValue.rounded(.towardZero)
            print ("reminder of \(decimalNumber) by \(divisor) = \((decimalNumber/divisor) - Decimal(whole))")
            if (decimalNumber/divisor) - Decimal(whole)  == 0.0 {
                result.append(divisor);
            }

            divisor += 0.1
        }
    return result
}

print(factors2(number: 20.0))
```

This solution gives the correct output. In the example, decimal factors of 20.0 (counting form 0.1 to 20.0) are:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 2, 2.5, 4, 5, 10, 20]
```